# Android tests are running without lanuching the emulator(choose device dialog not appears) - empty test suite

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin

I am struggling with running the tests under the androidTest folder - currently even when i am not launch the emulator the test runs without it, there is no dialog to force me to choose the device on which i must run the test.
It leads to problem, that when i run the test error appears in the console:

> Process finished with exit code 1
>   Class not found: "com.someapp.shoppinglistapp.ShoppingListDaoTest"Empty test suite.

Only when i manually Edit Configuration for this separate method choose the "deployment target options" and choose "open select deployment target dialog" it runs well, i choose the emulator and test runs. but this means that i will have to manually do it for every test method in my androidTest package.

What is really happening?
I've tried this even on brand new project, configured to be Kotlin project in Android Studio 3.0.1. You can try it for yourself.